# Why won't my Mongoose model load?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

This is my `locationsModel.js` file:

```
var LocationSchema, LocationsSchema, ObjectId, Schema, mongoose;
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
LocationSchema = {
  latitude: String,
  longitude: String,
  locationText: String
};
LocationsSchema = new Schema(LocationSchema);
LocationsSchema.method({
  getLocation: function(callback) {
    return console.log('hi');
  }
});
exports.Locations = mongoose.model('Locations', LocationsSchema, 'locations');
```

In my controller, I have:

```
var Locations, mongoose;
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Locations = require('../models/locationsModel').Locations;
exports.search = function(req, res) {
  var itemText, locationText;
  Locations.getLocation('info', function(err, callback) {
    return console.log('calleback');
  });
  return;
};
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function model() {
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
  } has no method 'getLocation'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your controller instead of `Locations = require('../models/locationsModel').Locations;` you can simply go `Locations = mongoose.model('Locations')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is statics rather than a method.

As per the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html):

I think you should define the `getLocations` function as follows (looking at your use of `getLocations` you've got a string parameter as well as the callback:

```
LocationsSchema.statics.getLocation = function(param, callback) {
    return console.log('hi');
}
```

EDIT:

The difference between `statics` and `methods` is whether you are calling it on the "type" or "objects" of that type. Adapted from the [examples](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/examples/schema.js):

```
BlogPostSchema.methods.findCreator = function (callback) {
  return this.db.model('Person').findById(this.creator, callback);
}
```

which you'd invoke as such:

```
BlogPost.findById(myId, function (err, post) {
  if (!err) {
    post.findCreator(function(err, person) {
      // do something with the creator
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow - awesome! So when would I use a `static` vs a `method`?